# Downloading from iCloud, files truncated, fine from other sources

Tags: swift, icloud, nsfilemanager

I'm using this code which is a mildly doctored version of an online tutorial. I understand the parts, but when I run it, the downloads happen, I get an error-free completion message. But the resulting file is truncated at 209 bytes (should be much larger).

```
    func dl( request: URL, dest: URL) {
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                // Success
                if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                    print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                }
                
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: dest)
                } catch (let writeError) {
                    print("Error creating file \(dest) : \(writeError)")
                }
                
            } else {
                print("Error while downloading. Error : %@", error?.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

The source file is on my iCloud, with permissions set to anyone with the link. When I try urls on other sites, it works fine.

I haven't been able to find a reliable, recent guide to doing what I'm trying to do, but from iCloud.... what am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `startDownloadingUbiquitousItem()`? Did you check the downloaded data?

Comment: Perhaps! But I can't find anything that indicates how to contextualize that. Do you or anyone else know where some clear guide to what is probably nothing like as obfuscated as this seems to be? Really, I just want to pull down files from iCloud, preferably as data into my app....

Comment: But what's the downloaded data? What if there it's an "error text" with info? Did you check what you've downloaded? Is it really the start of the file? But the previous method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410377-startdownloadingubiquitousitem seems to be the way.

Comment: I'll check out that. There is no error thrown, and what I guess I'm inquiring about is, does a url on iCloud, where the directory is "anyone with the link", act as a normal file server, allowing me (in theory) to plug in the url and download it? Whatever I d/l from iCloud using this code is just 209 bytes of nothing, no error; but on other sites, like images on other websites, it's fine.

Comment: But just to be certain, you're saying that Filemanager.default.startDowrloadingUbiquitousItem(at: <url>) should work....right? And presumably what this is doing is just ensuring that the local file in my iCloud is on disk.... again, right? So from there I can copy it to somewhere or pull it in to the app...